# $CustomDataAdapter.getView(MainActivity.java:168)

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, imageview

Android App keeps crashing and I am getting the following crash report

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at lk.digitalarc.elan.MainActivity$CustomDataAdapter.getView(MainActivity.java:168)
at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2263)
at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1263)
at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1175)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChild(RelativeLayout.java:689)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:473)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:327)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2291)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1916)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1113)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1295)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5670)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The error began happening after I wrote a conditional code to update image src on an imageview

```
ImageView img = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imgDP);
// update display pic for message according to content
if (!burst.getBurstFile().isEmpty()) {
    img.setImageResource(R.drawable.dp_attachment);
} else if (!burst.getBurstImg().isEmpty()) {
    img.setImageResource(R.drawable.dp_pic);
}
```

I know this seems like something very basic but for the life of me I cant figure out what the problem is.

The version this app is build for sdk version 14 to 19. I have a suspension about the .Empty() function but am not sure.

Comment: what is line 168 and where is burst initialized

Answer (score 0):

As per the Adapter.getView() javadocs, you should always check that your ConvertView v is not null. I am guessing the reference to v in the line ImageView img = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imgDP); is what is causing the null pointer exception.